# strings in sorted order, except group all the strings that begin with 'x' first

Tags: python

Given a list of strings, return a list with the strings in sorted order, except group all the strings that begin with 'x' first.

e.g.

`['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']`

yields

`['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']`.

```
a=['bbb', 'ccc', 'axx', 'xzz', 'xaa']
a1=['mix', 'xyz','apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark','xz']
xlist=[]
def sort(s):
    for i in s:
        if i[0]=='x':
            xlist.append(i)
            s.remove(i)
    print sorted(xlist)+sorted(s) 
    del xlist[:]

sort(a)
sort(a1)
```

---

This code works as long as two list elements which start with x dont come together.
i.e I get proper output for list a1 but not for a can you help me understand why!

---

obtained output.

```
['xzz', 'axx', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'xaa']
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'xz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

Comment: does the problem has to do something with s.remove(i)??

Comment: Seems yes. You are not supposed to remove from list while iterating over it.

Comment: Try `for i in s[:]:` instead

Comment: @AshishKumarS were you able to solve this? you may accept an answer that helped, cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not suppose to remove from the list while iterating over it, try it with a deep copy:

```
a=['bbb', 'ccc', 'axx', 'xzz', 'xaa']
a1=['mix', 'xyz','apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark','xz']
xlist=[]
def sort(s):
    for elem in s[:]:
        if elem.startswith('x'):
           xlist.append(elem)
           s.remove(elem)
    print(sorted(xlist)+sorted(s))
    del xlist[:]

sort(a)
sort(a1)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['xaa', 'xzz', 'axx', 'bbb', 'ccc']
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'xz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `sorted` or `list.sort` with two keys:

```
l = ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']
sorted(l, key=lambda x: (not x.startswith('x'), x))
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

where `not x.startswith('x')` returns `bool`, which gets sorted in `False` first. Thus, `not x.startswith('x')` grabs the strs that start with 'x' and bring them to the front.

Comment: `False` is of type `bool`, which is a subclass of `int`. `False` is defined to have int value `0` (and `True` is defined to have int value `1`). Thus, when creating tuples with `(0, "..")` for strings that start with "x" and `(1, "...")` for strings that don't start with "x", regular comparison of tuples will ensure that the strings starting with "x" comes first.